# Google Analytics Tracking ID Field disabled in Lightning Community

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, google-analytics

I'm trying to add a Google Analytics tracking ID to a new Lightning community. When I try to add the ID to the community builder config, I find that the field is disabled. The communities I've tried this with are developer and partial editions, and have been published at least once.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that you have completed this step. Experience Builder, go to Settings| Security. Under Content Security Policy, choose Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to Whitelisted Third-party Hosts.

Comment: Ugh I'm an idiot... that was it.  Don't know how I missed that in the documentation.  If you want to create an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have completed this step.

Goto Experience Builder, go to Settings| Security. Under Content Security Policy, choose Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to Whitelisted Third-party Hosts.